# Is it possible to create a subversion "profile" that only downloads specified directories in a repo when I check out?

Tags: svn

Is it possible to create a subversion "profile" that only downloads specified directories in a repo when I check out?

For example, my company has a huge repo that takes 10+ minutes to download. I only use a small subsection of directories. The way our architecture is set up, we have to check our repo out on 10+ machines depending on where we're deploying changes. Rather than check out the entire repository every time, I'd like to be able to check out just the directories I use.

For example, let's say our directory structure looks like this:

```
animals
animals/cats
animals/cats/tabby
animals/cats/siamese
animals/dogs
animals/dogs/pug
animals/dogs/lab
plants
plants/fern
plants/fern/green
plants/fern/brown
plants/ivy
plants/ivy/poison
plants/ivy/annoying
bridges
bridges/sf
bridges/sf/bay
bridges/sf/goldengate
bridges/ny
bridges/ny/brooklyn
bridges/ny/manhattan
bridges/ny/allotherbridges
```

Let's say I only want:

```
animals/cats/tabby
plants/*
bridges/ny/brooklyn/*
bridges/ny/manhattan/*
```

Can I set up a profile where regardless of where I type "svn co", it only downloads those four directories and their contents?

Answer (score 0):

no.  you could write a script that simulates that...  However you really may want to look into re-working your repo layout to match your needs.  It seems you have multiple projects co-mingled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) for this.  You might do something like:

-- directory structure

```
/animals
/bridges
...
/distributions
    /ny-tabbies
```

-- rough idea of externals property to set (e.g., with `propedit`)

```
> svn propget svn:external /distributions/ny-tabbies
../animals/cats/tabby tabby
../plants plants
../bridges/ny ny-bridges
```